# How to save UIWebView font size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I know that I can increase/decrease font size, by using `-webkit-text-size-adjust`, but I ran into problem with saving this font size into NSUserDefaults, because `-webkit-text-size-adjust` can only use percents.

For example. My font-size is 100%, I increase it to 110% and save it in NSUserDefaults. Next time when I want to increase it to 115% it will be much bigger than if I have increased 100% to 115%, and this happens because `1,1 * 1,15 != 1,0 * 1,15`. I've tried to fix it so this equality became true, but then I found out that after I have saved it and opened WebView, fontSize would be different.

**UPDATE:**
1) First time `font-size:110%`
[image]

2)Let's increase font-size to 125%
 
[image]

3)We have saved `font-size:125%` in `NSUserDefaults`. Let's restart application. So the first `font-size` will be `125%`
[image]

As you can see the font sizes are different. I can provide more screenshots with more strange behaviors, like when you hit decrease font-size from it's actually is getting bigger, but I thing now you understand my problem more accurately.

Comment: So, setting to 115% does not work? Do you mean that each subsequent adjustment of `-webkit-text-size-adjust` takes the current value as base?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work if you saved the _percent_, not the absolute size? i.e., if you save 110% in the defaults, wouldn't both the 110% and 115% be in relation to the same base size, which you haven't changed?

Comment: It does work. But as I found out percent is a relative value, not absolute. So everything depend on what was the starting point. 120% will be different if your starting fontsize is 100% and 130%.

Comment: So when you set to 150% then to 200%, then to 110%, then to ..., ..., and then back to 150%, the actual font size will be identical for the first and last 150%?

Comment: @Arkku I've added screenshots